# Application error issue in android emulator "There was an network error"

Tags: android, http, ionic-framework

i run the ionic app on android after adding platform android i run it through

```
ionic emulate android -l -c
```

I am not getting why this is coming, its android manifest file is:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.greatdevelopers.hrstop" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/multi_app_name" android:name="com.synconset.MultiImageChooserActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

its showing me this issue. Any solution of this please tell me.

[image: Error message getting]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add cordova whitelist under your project. Try the following -

$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: you'll need to add the following to your index.html meta tags: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

Answer (score 2):

Just add these two lines in config.xml

`<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="80000" />`

`<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />`