# Phonegap (Application error... Network error occured)

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have created a build using phonegap. In the index.html file i have written a simple iframe for loading a website. Its working when i take the local url from the phonegap. But its not working if i upload the whole build as a zip in phonegap and then download the apk file from it. Then tried to install that apk in phone its showing the application error.

I have already checked the access origin and also tried to give the domain name inside it. But its not at all working. Can anybody please help me on this.

config.xml and index.html given like this below

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" height="640px" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes">
</iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this page --  https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy  -- (<!-- Allow iframe to https://cordova.apache.org/ -->)-- that should do it. Let me know ill post it as an answer

Comment: It appears that because of the same origin policy it is not possible to load a website from a different domain into your app this way, did you give [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) a try?

Comment: @Tasos its not working :(. Still shows a blank white screen :(

Comment: @Blauharley Yes the issue is that i can't even load an external url in the build other items are all showing perfectly. If i load an external url its showing a blank page or the above error mentioned. Tried many access origin but still facing the issue. See my code its a simple iframe loading but still issue occures

Comment: Am using https://build.phonegap.com/ to build the apk file.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem and found an answer here: [Application error issue in android emulator "There was an network error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473814/application-error-issue-in-android-emulator-there-was-an-network-error)

Solution was to add cordova whitelist.

$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist

Answer (score 3):

You have made a common mistake. You need to apply the `whitelist` system. It is required as of [Cordova Tools 5.0.0](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html) (April 21, 2015). For *Phonegap Build*, that means since [`cli-5.1.1`](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/) (16 Jun 2015)

This *whitelist* worksheet should help.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Add this to your `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"      source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
```

**NOTE: YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**

Add the following to your `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

**NOTE: YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**