# Cordova net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_assets/www/)

Tags: android, reactjs, cordova, create-react-app

I know these type of question has been asked before but none of them works for me.

**My objective:** To build a cordova/phonegap app using react.

**What I did:** I created a basic cordova app. Deleted the contents of `/www` folder. Created a react app using `create-react-app`. Then built it using `npm run build` and copied the `build` folder content to `/www` of cordova. I'm following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336924/cordova-with-create-react-app). After building the cordova app, the app successfully runs on browser but it gives `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_assets/www/)` error when I try to run it on android.
To solve the issue, I even tried to add timeout and checked for spellings of files. But the issue still persists.

Please help me to find the solution for this issue.

Comment: you may missed out some files within www folder,i assume it may be an image or js file.

Comment: @veeran I checked index.html and other files are present in `\platforms\android\assets\www`

Answer (score 1):

You Should Add  `<allow-intent href="*" />` to your config.xml