# onDeviceReady event listener in react component

Tags: reactjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, react-dom

In my react app, I am trying to use a Cordova plugin ([cordovo-plugin-device](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device)) to get user's device version as follows

```
class LogoHeader extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    window.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady)
  }
  onDeviceReady () {
    console.log(device.cordova)
  }
  render () {
    ...
  }
}
```

But for some reason, the `deviceready` event never gets fired. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to listen to DOM events in react ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html#quick-example) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43440380/5421321) you should add the listener in your entry file (probably `index.js`)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

const startApp = () => {
    console.log(device.cordova)
    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
}

if(!window.cordova) {
  startApp()
} else {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', startApp, false)
}
```

You could also pass down `device.cordova` as props to `App` so you could access it in other components.

```
...
ReactDOM.render(
      <App device={device
         ? device.cordova
         : null}/>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
...
```